# Periodicity and spatial frequecy of function

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I know this should be really simple but for some reason I'm having an absolute mental block.

I'm trying to determine the period and spatial frequency of the following function,

$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{n} \sin(\frac{nx}{a}) $

I know sine is periodic around 2$\pi$ so I assume $\frac{nx}{a}T =  2\pi $ and so $T= \frac{2\pi a}{n x}$, is this correct? I have a feeling that becuase the function dependent on $x$ we must first move it to the time domain to get its period. Am I being ridiculous

As for the spatial frequency, is it simply the inverse of this as usual?

$f = \frac{1}{T} = \frac{nx}{2\pi a}$

If someone could give me a slap and knock my undergraduate/high school maths back into me, I'd appreciate it

Comment: Set the argument of the $\sin$ equal to $2\pi$ and solve for $x$. The function $f(x)$ will repeat at the longest period so set $n=1$ and then $T=x$. The fundamental frequency is indeed $f={1\over T}$ but there are also frequency components at $2 \over T$ and $3 \over T$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I just needed some one to spell it out for me on this occasion!

Comment: This time it is also just the longest period, but you usually want to look for the least common multiple of the periods